# Tell TypeScript that file will be included with script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, scope, frontend

I'm using TypeScript for some **front-end** JavaScript, and I'm loading two scripts from `index.html` like so:

```
<script src="replacements.js"></script>
<script src="socket.js"></script>
```

`replacements.ts` (which compiles into replacements.js) defines a function `insertReplacement` and looks like this:

```
export = 0;
import IReplacement from "../src/IReplacement";

// insertReplacement is defined in the global scope 
function insertReplacement(rep : IReplacement) : void {
    // ...
}
```

The `export = 0` is needed to suppress the `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });` line that tsc adds, since this line causes an error when **run in a browser.**

`socket.ts` uses this function, which since `socket.js` is loaded after `replacements.js`, should be available in the global scope (just as if these files were the same). `socket.ts` looks like this:

```
export = 0;
import IReplacement from "../src/IReplacement";

var docs: IReplacement[];
// populate `docs` here
docs.forEach((doc) => insertReplacement(doc))
// tsc:               ^ cannot find name 'insertReplacement'
```

`IReplacement` is a type used by both files on the client side (`replacements.ts` and `socket.ts`) as well as other files on the server side. It looks like this:

```
export default interface IReplacement {
    // ...
}

export {IReplacement};
```

Unfortunately, when I try to `tsc`, I get the error "cannot find name `insertReplacement`" in `socket.ts`. **Is there some way to tell the compiler that this function will be available at runtime?**

---

(In case it's useful, here's the compiler options from `tsconfig.json`):

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true
 }
```

(this `tsconfig.json` also compiles some back-end Node code as well as the front-end code)

Comment: It's not a global though you're using an import statement. That means it is a module.

Answer (score 3):

`insertReplacement` is NOT in the global scope.  You are setting up modules and it will not be in the global scope.

Your `replacement.ts` script will output this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    // insertReplacement is defined in the global scope 
    function insertReplacement(rep) {
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
});
```

([source](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0Aimport%20IReplacement%20from%20%22..%2Fsrc%2FIReplacement%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20insertReplacement%20is%20defined%20in%20the%20global%20scope%20%0D%0Afunction%20insertReplacement(rep%20%3A%20IReplacement)%20%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%7D))

See why now?  It should be as simple as this:

`replacements.ts`

```
// insertReplacement is defined in the global scope 
function insertReplacement(rep : IReplacement) : void {
    // ...
}
```

`socket.ts`

```
var docs: IReplacement[];
// populate `docs` here
docs.forEach((doc) => insertReplacement(doc))
// tsc:               ^ cannot find name 'insertReplacement'
```

Now it is all global scoped.  The `socket.ts` script does not need to import the other file to pickup the types when done this way.

Tip: I would STRONGLY recommend using a `namespace` block to get your code out of the global scope to pollute it as less possible (or learn how to use modules properly [you'd have to start by removing `export = 0;` and export the function instead]).

Comment: This doesn't work; removing the import statement means that neither `replacements.ts` nor `socket.ts` can access `IReplacement` (which I should add is a module).

Comment: You said _"`socket.ts` uses this function, which ... should be available in the global scope"_.  If that is true, then the answer is correct.  If you need modules then the answer tells you clearly to learn modules properly and gives a hint on how to get started. If you are loading modules, then you DON'T include them also into your web page using script tags. You have to choose one or the other.